# Combination explosion of an enum value (729 combinations...)

Tags: c++, enums, combinations, metaprogramming

im facing a problem in which I have to generate a huge amount of code, all of it fairly similar, and I want to know if there is any way to templatized.

Lets say I have a structure of this type

```
template <typename ...NodeKindTs>
struct Element{
std::tuple<NodeKindTs...> nodes;
}
```

I have a vector of ints which related a Node with another, and a vector of an enum which says which kind of Node is each. The kind can be A, B or C.

```
enum class Kind {A,B,C};
std::vector<int> relationShip;
std::vector<Kind> kind;
```

For example, if I have

```
relationShip = {1,2,-1};
kind = {A,B,A}
```

would mean that the first node is of kind A and is related to the second node, which is of kind B. You get it.

Now, I have to create Elements and insert them into a vector depending on the NodeKind that each node and the relation ship. This Elements are templatized by up to 6 NodeKinds. For solving this, I need a huge if that check the Kind of each node and then call the Element ctor.

For the 2 NodeKinds case, this means doing something like

```
if (node1.type == A && node2.type == A) {
auto &simNode1 = containerOfAs(node1.id);
auto &smiNode2 = containerOfAs(node2.id);
insertElement(elementFactory(simNode1, simNode2));
}
if (node1.type == A && node2.type == C) 
{
auto &simNode1 = containerOfAs(node1.id);
auto &smiNode2 = containerOfCs(node2.id);
insertElement(elementFactory(simNode1, simNode2));
}
if (node1.type == B && node2.type == C) 
{
auto &simNode1 = containerOfBs(node1.id);
auto &smiNode2 = containerOfCs(node2.id);
insertElement(elementFactory(simNode1, simNode2));
}
...
```

inserElement is a meta-function I have create which insert the element into the container if fits in from a list of containers.

For this 2 case, this requires up to 9 ifs. For the 3 case it requires 27 ifs and for the 6 case it requires 729 ifs. I really dont want to code them.

Any idea on how I could solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds sort of like how a similar issue was solved in Boost Units.  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_units.html

Comment: You can still use `std::variant` to let it doing the combination for you... I'm afraid that it will slow down compilation though.

Comment: @Jarod42 how would you use std::variant to solve this. Ive been thinking about it, but havent found an answer.

Comment: @Eljay Ive been looking at the documentation of Boost.Units, but I havent found a similar problem. Can you point me a little bit more? Thanks!

Comment: Boost Units uses parameterized templates for various permutations of the SI units.  Maybe I've misunderstood the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `std::variant`, you might have something like:

```
std::variant<std::reference_wrapper<NodeA>,
             std::reference_wrapper<NodeB>,
             std::reference_wrapper<NodeC>> getNodeAsVariant(Kind kind, int id)
{
    switch (kind) {
        case Kind::A: return containerOfAs(id);
        case Kind::B: return containerOfBs(id);
        case Kind::C: return containerOfCs(id);
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid kind");
}
```

And then

```
auto v1 = getNodeAsVariant(node1.type, node1.id);
auto v2 = getNodeAsVariant(node2.type, node2.id);
auto v3 = getNodeAsVariant(node3.type, node3.id);
auto v4 = getNodeAsVariant(node4.type, node4.id);
auto v5 = getNodeAsVariant(node5.type, node5.id);
auto v6 = getNodeAsVariant(node6.type, node6.id);

// r1, .., r6 would be the correct reference_wrapper<T>
std::visit([](auto r1, auto r2, auto r3, auto r4, auto r5, auto r6) {
         insertElement(elementFactory(r1/*.get()*/, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6));
    }, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6);
```

So `std::visit` would generate the 729 overloads for you.

Comment: The element factory receives a reference to the node (in this case, a reference_wrapper). Is the variant converted implicitly to its underlying type? How does it know it has to be converted to type NodeA or type NodeB?

Comment: `std::visit` does the magic and according to `v1.index()`, calls the correct overloads corresponding to `f(std.get<v1.index()>(v1), std.get<v2.index()>(v2))` (`std.get<v1.index()>(v1)` is invalid as `v1.index()` is runtime, but I hope you get the idea).

Comment: That's nice. I thought on a solution like that, but I wasn't sure it works, as I thought you need to know at compile time the overload. Im testing it right now with the 2 type case. Do you know if it would work with Boost.Variant? Thanks!

Comment: `boost::variant` has `boost:: apply_visitor`.(but it seems you need to inherit from `boost::static_visitor` so creating dedicated struct instead of lambda).

Comment: Still not working. I have created the visitor lambda and Im passing the two variants of the 2 type case. I get a compiler error saying there's no overload of the factory receiving variants. My factory is a template which receives two references of T1 and T2 (for the 2 type case) and return the Element<T1, T2>.

Comment: Looks fine in godbolt.org. Compiles and runs as expected. Ill double check my production code to see where's the error. Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4bc0577b7238c15f) (only 3 varaibles, as using 6 variables takes too much time for online compilers).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this can be used as a starting point (I may have misunderstood the question and there are probably ways to make it shorter):

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Kind { A, B, C };

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Kind k) {
    switch (k) {
        case Kind::A: return os << "A";
        case Kind::B: return os << "B";
        case Kind::C: return os << "C";
    }
    return os << "Unknown";
}


template<typename F>
void dispatch(Kind k, F f) {
    switch (k) {
        case Kind::A: f.template call<Kind::A>(); return;
        case Kind::B: f.template call<Kind::B>(); return;
        case Kind::C: f.template call<Kind::C>(); return;
    }
    abort();
}

template<Kind k1>
struct handle2 {
    template<Kind k2>
    void call() {
        std::cout << "k1=" << k1 << " k2=" << k2 << "\n";
        // Do your thing with k1 and k2 here
    }
};

struct handle1 {
    Kind k2;
    template<Kind k1>
    void call() {
        dispatch(k2, handle2<k1>{});
    }
};

void handle(Kind k1, Kind k2) {
    dispatch(k1, handle1{k2});
}

int main() {
    handle(Kind::C, Kind::B);
}
```

Comment: I cant see how this solves the problem. Your dispatch function takes two enum values. As I said, I can have up to 6 values. Also, you dont use NodeKind for anything, so how do you create the Element<> type?

Comment: Well, like I wrote I may have misunderstood your question, so I only sketched what I thought would be a solution for 2 values. It's still not 100% clear to me what you need, but I'd create the Element in `handle2.call` (possibly passing references to the needed context along the way). If I'm totally off base just let me know and I'll delete the answer.

Comment: I need to create an Element<T1, T1, T1> if I have Enum1, Enum1, Enum1 combination, Element<T2, T1, T2> if I have Enum2, Enum1, Enum2 and so on. For two types is easy, its only combinations (given 3 values for the enum). For more types, it becomes too much typing and i was looking a way to generate the Element automatically. Can you try to depict a 3 type system to see if I can understand better how to extend it? Thanks!