# Create a type list combination of types in C++

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, cartesian-product

Im trying to create some tool to create a list of types based on combinations of other types.

Lets say we have three types

```
struct A{};
struct B{};
struct C{};
```

I want to get a list of tuples which has every possible combination of N types A,B or C.

For a N=2 case, this would be

```
std::tuple<A,A>
std::tuple<A,B>
std::tuple<A,C>
std::tuple<B,A>
std::tuple<B,B>
std::tuple<B,C>
std::tuple<C,A>
std::tuple<C,B>
std::tuple<C,C>
```

The idea is to create a tuple which holds a container for all those types, so I can later store any of those types inside the container list.

```
template <typename ...Combinations>
using CombinationList = std::tuple<std::vector<Combinations>...>;
```

I already have a mechanism to inserting a particupar element inside the container in which it fits, but I have no clue on how to create the combinatios.

On the comments people has suggestes using `std::vector<Combination<std::variant<A,C,B>, std::variant<A,B,C>>>`. Althought this technically solve the problem, I prefer not to use it, as A, B C and has very different sizes and I dont want to visit the variants at runtime.  Also, at some point I will need to upload the all the data in the containers in

```
std::tuple<std::vector<Combination>...>
```

to the GPU, so I cant use std::variant here.

How could I do this?

Thanks!

PD: This is related to this question [Combination explosion of an enum value (729 combinations...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54988431/combination-explosion-of-an-enum-value-729-combinations)
In that question I asked how I could generate easily the types that would go inside the container. Now I need to generate the containers .

Comment: A `std::variant` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) would be a lot less work.

Comment: How would you do it? Im not sure how to implemented using a variant...

Comment: How about using something like `std::vector<std::tuple<std::variant<A, B, C>, std::variant<A, B, C>>>`?

Comment: A, B and C can have very different sizes. This is for a physics simulator, during bootstrap I dont care about performance, but during simulation I care (a lot) about it. That why I prefer not to use a variant like that. Also, at some point I will to upload all the data to GPU

Comment: @jjcasmar I am more less sure it is possible because generating combinations can be done statelessly. Writing it would be tough yet possible chore

Comment: You cannot create a vector that holds objects of different types. There is no such thing in C++. Your options are (1) vector of variants or (2) vector to (smart) pointers to some (abstract) base class, whereas derived classes are responsible for concrete types.

Comment: @jjcasmar: "*This is for a physics simulator*" That sounds very much like you're trying to take an OOP approach to multi-object collision. Giving each object a different type, and then having functions for each of the cross product of the possible interacting types.That's the wrong approach to take, and it will only end in tears.

Comment: Do you require the container to contain more than one tuple at a time? What's wrong with having a `struct` that contains an `A`, a `B`, and a `C` and just ignoring one of them, using whatever mechanism you use to select the tuple member you want?

Comment: Is not for a collision system. Is for the computation of forces. Giving an Element which contains nodes which can be A, B or C, I need the 3d position of the nodes to compute the forces of the element. I dont want to pay the check to decide which kind of node I have in the element while computing the forces. I can preproces it. I will have millions of elements, that's why I want to avoid as much computations as possible in the hot path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I already have a mechanism to inserting a particupar element inside the container in which it fits, but I have no clue on how to create the combinatios.

Suppose you have a list of types (say `A, B, C`) and an unsigned integer `N`, I propose a `using`

```
template <std::size_t N, typename ... Ts>
using Combinations = ???
```

that is defined as a `std::tuple` containing a list of `std::tuple`s with all combinations.

So, by example,

```
Combinations<2u, A, B, C>
```

become

```
  std::tuple<
      std::tuple<A,A>, std::tuple<A,B>, std::tuple<A,C>,
      std::tuple<B,A>, std::tuple<B,B>, std::tuple<B,C>,
      std::tuple<C,A>, std::tuple<C,B>, std::tuple<C,C>>
```

The following is a full compiling C++11 example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
constexpr std::tuple<T, Ts...> addTupleType (std::tuple<Ts...>);

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto addType ()
   -> std::tuple<decltype(addTupleType<T>(std::declval<Ts>()))...>;

template <typename ... Ts, typename ... Us>
constexpr auto getCombinations (std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0u>,
                                std::tuple<Ts...> t, std::tuple<Us ...> u)
   -> decltype( u );

template <std::size_t N, typename ... Ts, typename ... Us,
          typename std::enable_if<(N > 0u), bool>::type = true>
constexpr auto getCombinations (std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>,
                                std::tuple<Ts...> t, std::tuple<Us ...>)
   -> decltype (getCombinations(
         std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N-1u>{}, t,
         std::tuple_cat(addType<Ts, Us...>()...)));

template <std::size_t N, typename ... Ts>
using Combinations
   = decltype(getCombinations(
         std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N-1u>{},
         std::declval<std::tuple<Ts...>>(),
         std::declval<std::tuple<std::tuple<Ts>...>>()));

template <typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto CombListHelper (std::tuple<Ts...>)
   -> std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...>;

template <typename T>
using CombinationList = decltype(CombListHelper(std::declval<T>()));


int main()
 {
   using type_1 = Combinations<2u, A, B, C>;
   using type_2 = std::tuple<
      std::tuple<A,A>, std::tuple<A,B>, std::tuple<A,C>,
      std::tuple<B,A>, std::tuple<B,B>, std::tuple<B,C>,
      std::tuple<C,A>, std::tuple<C,B>, std::tuple<C,C>>;

   static_assert( std::is_same<type_1, type_2>::value, "!" );

   using type_3 = CombinationList<Combinations<2u, A, B, C>>;
   using type_4 = std::tuple<
      std::vector<std::tuple<A,A>>, std::vector<std::tuple<A,B>>,
      std::vector<std::tuple<A,C>>, std::vector<std::tuple<B,A>>,
      std::vector<std::tuple<B,B>>, std::vector<std::tuple<B,C>>,
      std::vector<std::tuple<C,A>>, std::vector<std::tuple<C,B>>,
      std::vector<std::tuple<C,C>>>;

   static_assert( std::is_same<type_3, type_4>::value, "!" );
 }
```

Comment: Althought is doesn't completely solve my problem, I think I can take this as a starting point. Now i only need to generate a vector for each one of the possible combinations. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jjcasmar - not sure to understand what do you exactly want but... answer improved with a `CombinationList` (see `type_3` and `type_4` in `main()`)

Comment: wow, impressive. This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks you very much!

Comment: `typename std::enable_if<(N > 0u), bool>::type = true` seems unneeded. overload with `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0u>` would be better match.

Comment: And, as there are only declarations, `constexpr` is unneeded too.

Comment: You might start at `getCombinations(
         std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>{},
         std::declval<std::tuple<Ts...>>(),
         std::declval<std::tuple<>>())` to handle `Combinations<0, Ts...>`.

Comment: @Jarod42 - I was convinced too that the `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0u>` would a better match (and that the SFINAE part was unneeded) but clang++ (that select the other version and gives error reaching the recursion limit) and g++ (that goes in loop and force me to reboot my computer) disagree. And I don't understand why.

Comment: @Jarod42 - Not so simple about start `getCombination()`: a not empty list inside the second `std::declval()` is needed to expand `Ts` in `addType()`; with your solution, `type_1` become `std::tuple<>`. But you're right: my solution has the defect that doesn't handle the `N == 0` case.

Comment: Oh, it seems due to return type determination... `getCombinations` hides the overload, using `::getCombinations` solves that [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f40d07522a489c3).

Answer (score 5):

Using the analogy with storing two dimensional matrix in linear storage, all possible pairs of `A`, `B` and `C` are labeled by one dimensional integers `0,1,...,8` like this:

```
0 -> (0/3, 0%3) = (0,0) -> std::tuple<A,A>
1 -> (1/3, 1%3) = (0,1) -> std::tuple<A,B>
...
8 -> (8/3, 8%3) = (2,2) -> std::tuple<C,C>
```

Thus we can construct the list of pairs as follows.
These functions work in C++14 and over.
For instance, `Combinations<A,B,C>::types` is equal to `std::tuple<std::vector<std::tuple<A,A>>, std::vector<std::tuple<A,B>>, ...>`:

[**Live DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/z/3ms1v_)

```
template<std::size_t I, typename Tuple>
struct make_pair_vector
{
    static constexpr std::size_t  left_index = I/std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value;
    static constexpr std::size_t right_index = I%std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value;

    using type = std::vector<
                    std::tuple<typename std::tuple_element< left_index, Tuple>::type,
                               typename std::tuple_element<right_index, Tuple>::type>>;
};

template <typename T, typename Is>
struct make_combinations;

template <typename Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
struct make_combinations<Tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    using tuples = std::tuple<typename make_pair_vector<Is, Tuple>::type...>;
};

template<typename ...Args>
struct Combinations
{
    using types = typename make_combinations
                    <std::tuple<Args...>,
                     std::make_index_sequence<(sizeof...(Args))*(sizeof...(Args))>>
                    ::tuples;
};
```

Comment: This is a nice try, but it only works for combinations of two elements (AA, AB, AC, AB), but doesnt work for three elements (AAA, ABB, AAB...) THanks you anyway, is a very nice code.

Comment: division and modulo to select the types... intriguing idea.

Comment: @jjcasmar (and max66), many thx. I hope you will go well. BTW, generalizing this approach to triples or more large dimensions may not be so difficult.

Comment: @Hiroki nice idea. May I edit your answer to the general case? Here is my proposal: https://wandbox.org/permlink/aAQ3ZJX73IfViZax .

Comment: @Julius Ah, nice code! But I want to keep current my answer because, simply, that is not my code :). Needless to say, you can post it as your own answer. Thank you anyway, nice work!