# All pairs of a set at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have a set of types:

```
struct A{};
struct B{};
struct B{};
```

and a test macro which creates a test for a pair of types:

```
#define GENERATE_TEST_(Type_1, Type_2) \
    Type1 t1;                          \
    Type2 t2;                          \
    ..                                 \
    // some complex test code          \
    ..                                 \
```

I call this inside the body of my Test as follows:

```
void Test() {
  GENERATE_TEST_(A,B)
  GENERATE_TEST_(B,C)
  GENERATE_TEST_(A,C)
}
```

The problem is that the list of types I have are going to grow in the order of tens and I need a way to automatically generate all pairs. With some Google searching, I figured this falls in the area of metaprogramming where I need to make the compiler generate this code at compile time. Is this too complex for non language experts? I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: In my experience, some simple code generation in a pre-build step is simpler and more flexible than joining the macro circus.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55005063/create-a-type-list-combination-of-types-in-c) helpful?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like google test? Maybe you may check their code.